# Run magit command in other-window/frame?

Tags: magit, window, frames

Is there a way to run magit commands so that the the command is run within a new window or a different frame?

For example, when running `magit-log-all-branches` (`l b`) from the `magit-status` window it would be nice to optionally split the window a la `switch-to-buffer-other-window`, so that it's possible to see both the log the status buffer at the same time.

As far as I can tell there are no prefix arguments or switches that accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be configured exactly to your liking, but it won't be easy and require quite a bit of reading. Start by reading about `magit-display-buffer-function` and friends [here](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Switching-Buffers.html). That's just a wrapper around `display-alist`, so read [about that](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html) too.